# sum values of many (upto n or unknown) dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like following :

```
dict_items([(True, 1), (None, 16)])
dict_items([(True, 3), (None, 15)])
```

and there number increases as number of user increases i.e it might go upto n. So I wanted to find the total number of true and none in total.

For the above data I want to find total_true = 4, total_none = 31

```
    care_needs_name = {
        "Communication": None,
        "Continence": None,
        "Daily life/lifestyle": None,
        "Death and dying": None,
        "Emotional support": None,
        "Finance": None,
        "Maintaining a safe environment": None,
        "Medical": None,
        "Medication": None,
        "Mental capacity": None,
        "Mobility": None,
        "Nutrition/hydration": None,
        "Personal care": None,
        "Religious/cultural/spiritual needs": None,
        "Sexuality": None,
        "Skin integrity": None,
        "Sleeping": None
    }



    care_plans = CarePlanNeed.objects.filter(resident=obj.resident)
    today = timezone.now()
    i = 0
    # sum = 0
    for care in care_plans:
        i += 1
        recent = care.history.first()
        next_review = recent.history_date + datetime.timedelta(30)
        if str(today) > str(next_review):
            care_needs_name[care.aspect_of_life] = next_review.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
        else:
            care_needs_name[care.aspect_of_life] = True
    counts = dict(Counter(care_needs_name.values()).items())
    print(counts.items())
    total_review_completed = 0
    total_review_to_add = 0
    for k, v in counts.items():
        if k == True:
            total_review_completed = total_review_completed + v
        else:
            total_review_to_add = total_review_to_add + v
    print(total_review_completed)
```

But for this I am getting :

```
dict_items([(True, 1), (None, 16)])
1
dict_items([(True, 3), (None, 15)])
3
```

Edit 2:

I have this queryset `<QuerySet [<CarePlanNeed: Communication( gbsd adcafv  (12 Nov 2019))>]>
<QuerySet [<CarePlanNeed: ads( asd asd  (05 Nov 2019))>, <CarePlanNeed: Communication( asd asd  (05 Nov 2019))>, <CarePlanNeed: Continence( asd asd  (05 Nov 2019))>]>`

Now I wanted to sum all the `CarePlanNeed` here sum = 4 i.e Communication + ads + Communication + Continence

Comment: You initial data can't be represented normally, give a normal example of input data.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have added the complete code and the data I hope you will understand what I wanted to calculate/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def func(dct_items):
    true = 0
    none = 0
    for key in range(0, len(dict_items)):
        if(dict_items[key][0] == True):
            true += dict_items[key][1]
        elif(dict_items[key][0] == None):
            none += dict_items[key][1]
    return true, none

total_true = 0
total_none = 0

dict_items = ([(True, 1), (None, 16)])
temp_true, temp_none = func(dict_items)
total_true += temp_true
total_none += temp_none

dict_items= ([(True, 3), (None, 15)])
temp_true, temp_none = func(dict_items)
total_true += temp_true
total_none += temp_none

print("Total True: " + str(total_true) + '\n')
print("Total None: " + str(total_none))
```

This gives you:

```
Total True: 4

Total None: 31
```

Comment: That is not the single dictionary, for now I have 2 user and for each 2 user I have 2 different dictionary. If I will have 100 user then I will have 100 different dictionary like
dict_items([(True, 1), (None, 16)])
dict_items([(True, 3), (None, 15)])
.
.
dict_items([(True, 4), (None, 14)])

Comment: I don't understand your edited code, but please see my updated answer if that solves your problem?

Comment: Is that what you look for?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

nr = int(input("Number of dictionaries: "))
dicts = []
for i in range(nr):
    a = int(input("True value for dictionary nr %d : " %i))
    b = int(input("None value for dictionary nr %d : " %i))
    dicts.append({'True': a, 'None': b})
c = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    c.update(d)
print(c)
```

You can modify the first part if you want other functionality.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem

Comment: That is just an general example based on your title. You can add all your dictionaries that are created in a single list by using append. Then you can go and iterate over all of them and counter your none and true values. So for example you have 100 users, store all their dictionaries in 1 list and then this part: c = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    c.update(d)
print(c) , will tell you the nr of true and none values